# why does Xcode 4.6.3 automatically insert viewDidUnload for me?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

After I link a view in Storyboard with ViewController, Xcode always automatically generate viewDidUnload method in ViewController file, But I don't want to generate it. So how to disable it?

Comment: What is the deployment target of your project? `viewDidUnload` is still used through iOS 5.x.

Comment: deployment target is iOS 5.x and 6.1,but how to disable automatically insert viewDidUnload

Comment: Do you have strong outlets and it adds code to nil the outlet?

Comment: viewDidUnload is generated if your deployment target is earlier than iOS6. If you don't want viewDidUnload to be generated don't deploy to iOS5 ;-)